# Manipulate pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
        colA   colB   
idcode
3223      s1   13
3223      s2   18
211       s1   24
211       s2   43
211       s3  198
```

where `colA` and `colB` are the columns and `idcode` is the index for rows.
I would like to have as output a df as follows:

```
        s1   s2  s3
idcode  
3223    13   18  nan(or 0 but I'd prefer nan)
211     24   43  198
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another way using `pivot()`:

```
df.pivot(columns='colA', values='colB')
colA      s1    s2     s3
idcode                   
211     24.0  43.0  198.0
3223    13.0  18.0    NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `set_index` and `unstack`

```
df.set_index('colA', append=True).colB.unstack()

colA      s1    s2     s3
idcode                   
211     24.0  43.0  198.0
3223    13.0  18.0    NaN
```

---

To get rid of the `colA` label on the `columns` object.

```
df.set_index('colA', append=True).colB.unstack().rename_axis(None, 1)

          s1    s2     s3
idcode                   
211     24.0  43.0  198.0
3223    13.0  18.0    NaN
```

---

**What if `idcode`/`colA` pairs are not unique?**
Then we have to aggregate.

**`pandas` `0.20`**
*`groupby`*

```
#                          This could be any thing
#                          that aggregates, mean, sum, etc.
#                                   /---\
df.groupby(['idcode', 'colA']).colB.first().unstack()

colA      s1    s2     s3
idcode                   
211     24.0  43.0  198.0
3223    13.0  18.0    NaN
```

*`pivot_table`*

```
df.pivot_table('colB', index='idcode', columns='colA', aggfunc='first')

colA      s1    s2     s3
idcode                   
211     24.0  43.0  198.0
3223    13.0  18.0    NaN
```

Comment: it works and if I understand correctly `df.set_index('EQT_ID', append=True)` is creating a multindex dataframe.